# need a quick way to double the contents of a table in mysql for test data

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to create a lot of extra records in a table as "test data" to show how different api calls perform with tables of various sizes.

I have a table with 1000 rows, including some columns which have "unique" indexes on them, and an auto-incrementing "id" column.

So for example, I have these fields:

```
id (auto inc. int)
user_id (unique int)
org_id (int)
type (string)
```

I'm hoping for a single SQL query that will double the contents of the table, and somehow allow for integers that cannot be duplicated (on account of unique index).

Something like:

"insert into mytable (select user_id, org_id, type from mytable)"

... but modified of course to actually work.

Comment: Please give an example of "including some columns which have "unique" indexes on them"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable to a value you can add to every ID to get an unused ID. Then you can add this to the original `user_id` when inserting.

```
SET @offset = (SELECT MAX(user_id) - MIN(user_id) + 1 FROM mytable);

INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, org_id, type)
SELECT user_id + @offset, org_id, type
FROM mytable
```

Comment: perfect! thanks for the tip.